# Execute bash command terminal at run time with bash function

Tags: command-line, bash

When i open the terminal i want the following command to be executed automatically, by a bash script.

```
newgrp docker
.... 
possible other commands
```

The reason i want this to be done through a bash script is for me to learn how to run automation when i open a terminal.

PseudoCode:

```
Start
function
if terminal is running for the first time
execute commands
else if programs to be executed by commands are running already
don't run again
End
```

I tried adding the command `newgrp docker` to .bashrc end, it breaks my terminal.

Comment: Since `~/.bashrc` is used for all your `bash`scripts, it's the wrong place for `newgrp`. Read `man sudo` and use `sudo -g docker ...`.

Comment: Do you want your script(s) to run only when Terminal is opened? Or do you also want these scripts to run if you SSH into your machine?

Comment: @Matigo, that is a good question. I run Ubuntu as main. I think would be nice to run automatically. But I'd still like to learn how to run a function to execute commands when i open a terminal.

Comment: What command(s) did you add to your .bashrc, and in what way did the terminal "break"?

Comment: @steeldriver edited my post

Comment: In what way did your terminal break?